# Severless Framework Skip Docker Build for ECS/Lambda

Tags: serverless-framework

Is it possible to conditionally skip re-building Docker images when deploying a Serverless Framework service?   When doing updates and trying to test small infrastructure/CF updates (non-application changes), it would nice to be able to deploy directly with the current images for ECS and Lambda to test these changes without doing a rebuild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no easy built-in way of doing this. One of the workarounds would be to replace the image definition to point directly to an image in ECR that is currently being used by the function(s) during the infra-only deployments.